# Passing docstring of a function to another file python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, openapi, flask-apispec

I'm using apispec in order to generate openapi specification (swagger) to be used for further utilization in AWS.

I was trying to optimize my current file by creating another file that contains functions with docstrings related to the routes implemented.
I'm still not sure if it is possible or not but what I'm sure about is that it didn't worked for me.
Here's what I've implemented so far:

The function below *login_doc()* inside the file *login_file.py* contains the docstring related to the *login* route.

```
def login_doc():
"""
post:
  responses:
    "200":
      description: "200 response"
      content:
        application/json:
          schema:
          $ref: "#/components/schemas/Empty"
"""
pass
```

And in the file *generate_openapi.py* I did this:

```
import login_file

@app.route('/login', methods=['POST'])
def login():
  login_file.login_doc.__doc__
```

PS: the rest of the imports are working just fine, just removed them when posting this question.

Unfortunately, this does not work for me. As I said before, I'm trying to minimize the lines of code of *generate_openapi.py* so that it can be more readable and comprehensible. Thank you all in advance for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I doubt that it aids readability, if you define the docstring outside the function, you can set the docstring after defining the function, like so:

```py
import login_file

@app.route('/login', methods=['POST'])
def login():
  ...

login.__doc__ = login_file.login_doc.__doc__
```

Alternatively, define a decorator to change the docstring of your function.

Comment: Thank you @larsl for your response, actually this can fix the problem!